# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes after long time run

Tags: drivers, 16.04, freeze

I am facing strange problem after I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.01 in my notebook. This notebook is a server and is supposed to run all the time. But it runs only a couple of hours before it crashed out. After crashed, keyboard, mouse or remote connection does not work, its like shutdown. To work it again, I have to hard restart the system from power button.

I am expecting some sort of solution of this problem from you guys, who has already faced similar problem.

Basically, I have searched the problem online, got several workarounds, but nothing worked.

1. **ACPI**  I added "acpi=off" /etc/default/grub, restarted after grub-update, but did not work.
2. **NTP** I have installed and activated NTP server. I got several errors from NTP Server. I checked the */var/log/syslog*, where I found the following NTP related error:

```
Nov 21 23:42:22 frtest0009 ntpd[1756]: error resolving pool ntp.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
Nov 21 23:42:42 frtest0009 ntpd[1756]: error resolving pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
Nov 21 23:43:02 frtest0009 ntpd[1756]: error resolving pool 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
Nov 21 23:43:22 frtest0009 ntpd[1756]: error resolving pool ntp.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
Nov 21 23:43:43 frtest0009 ntpd[1756]: error resolving pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
Nov 21 23:44:03 frtest0009 ntpd[1756]: error resolving pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
Nov 21 23:44:23 frtest0009 ntpd[1756]: error resolving pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
Nov 21 23:44:43 frtest0009 ntpd[1756]: error resolving pool 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
```

Finally below is the error just before system crashed:

```
Nov 22 00:09:27 frtest0009 ntpd[1756]: Soliciting pool server 91.189.91.157
Nov 22 00:09:27 frtest0009 ntpd[1756]: Soliciting pool server 188.40.99.69
Nov 22 00:09:27 frtest0009 ntpd[1756]: Soliciting pool server 192.53.103.108
Nov 22 00:10:29 frtest0009 ntpd[1756]: Soliciting pool server 213.95.200.110
Nov 22 00:10:29 frtest0009 ntpd[1756]: Soliciting pool server 176.9.253.76
Nov 22 00:10:34 frtest0009 ntpd[1756]: Soliciting pool server 148.251.68.100
Nov 22 00:10:34 frtest0009 ntpd[1756]: Soliciting pool server 37.120.191.49
Nov 22 00:10:35 frtest0009 ntpd[1756]: Soliciting pool server 91.189.89.198
```

I am really suspicious, whether NTP server is malfunctioning to crash the system. I am not sure about that.

3. **journalctl -p 3** I have used this command to get the following errors.

```
Nov 21 15:50:35 frtest0009 root[3898]: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/avahi-autoipd returned non-zero exit status 1
Nov 21 15:51:37 frtest0009 kernel: [drm:wait_panel_status [i915]] *ERROR* Panel status timeout: status 08000001 control 00000000
Nov 21 15:56:57 frtest0009 kernel: [drm:wait_panel_status [i915]] *ERROR* Panel status timeout: status 08000001 control 00000000
Nov 21 15:58:02 frtest0009 kernel: [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request.
Nov 21 16:04:25 frtest0009 kernel: [drm:wait_panel_status [i915]] *ERROR* Panel status timeout: status 08000001 control 00000000
Nov 21 16:09:45 frtest0009 kernel: [drm:wait_panel_status [i915]] *ERROR* Panel status timeout: status 08000001 control 00000000
Nov 21 16:12:58 frtest0009 kernel: [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request.
Nov 21 16:15:05 frtest0009 kernel: [drm:wait_panel_status [i915]] *ERROR* Panel status timeout: status 08000001 control 00000000
Nov 21 16:20:25 frtest0009 kernel: [drm:wait_panel_status [i915]] *ERROR* Panel status timeout: status 08000001 control 00000000
Nov 21 16:27:54 frtest0009 kernel: [drm:wait_panel_status [i915]] *ERROR* Panel status timeout: status 08000001 control 00000000
Nov 21 16:33:13 frtest0009 kernel: [drm:wait_panel_status [i915]] *ERROR* Panel status timeout: status 08000001 control 00000000
Nov 21 16:37:48 frtest0009 root[4407]: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/avahi-autoipd returned non-zero exit status 1
Nov 21 16:38:33 frtest0009 kernel: [drm:wait_panel_status [i915]] *ERROR* Panel status timeout: status 08000001 control 00000000
```

Please note here, the error message *Panel status timeout" status 08000001 control 00000000*  I have no idea, what does this message mean, is it a serious error?

4. **lspci** This command produces the following output (just for information)

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
00:12.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SDIO Controller (rev 0e)
00:13.0 IDE interface: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SATA IDE Controller (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 0e)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 0e)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series USB EHCI (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
```